# I Can't delete files after booting into Windows 10

Tags: files, delete

I have a dual boot, Ubuntu 22.04 and Windows 10. After booting into Windows 10, I can no longer delete any files or folders in Ubuntu. Even if I open Nautilus as sudo it will still not allow me to delete anything. It does show a lock on the drive folders in /mnt/Drive_Folder.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered Windows was not shutting down completely and this somehow prevented me from having permissions in Ubuntu. I turned off "fast start" under power management Windows and it allowed the computer to shutdown completely and allow me to delete files in Ubuntu

Comment: Turning off fast start and hibernation is essential on dual boot - as you’ll have discovered, windows leaves the file system in an unsafe state so Ubuntu won’t touch it apart from read only.